# How to stream and grab frames from a video file to test real-time processing in Python

Tags: python, opencv, real-time

I'm working on a project that will eventually have to process webcam images in real-time. I have some suitable test videos that I use to test my program. However, I don't know how to simulate real-time processing with a video file. I can read in each frame and process it, but this is not realistic since the algorithm is too heavy to run on every frame. I would like to 'stream' the video separately and pull in a frame each time the algorithm starts to test with a realistic fps, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic layout of the code you can use :

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path to video file')
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # destroy all opened windows
```

Comment: That is similar to how I have it right now, but this reads the frames one for one. That is, there are no skipped frames.